# Consulta Api Rest de Gmail

Tags: jquery, nodejs, angular, vue.js, reactjs

Tengo una gran duda sobre las Apis en formato Json , cual es la mejor forma de consumirlas.. se consumen en en el backend (node.js) o las consumo por medio de un framework de javascript (Vue-React-Angular).

Pregunto porque estoy un poco perdido a donde me tengo que enfocar para consumirlas..

PD: un amigo me dijo usa jquery .. pero no se si sera la mejor idea o forma de hacerlo..

Agradezco todo tipo de ayuda y acepto opiniones en caso de estar mal enfocado.

EDIT: 
tienen razon deberia haber mencionado que quiero usar API de gmail y llevarlas a mi aplicacion nodejs.. es por ello que si debo enfocarme o consumirlas en el frontend o backend .. cual es lo optimo .. o no hay misterio en ello y solo se consumen con algun framework

Saludos mIl gracias

Comment: Trata de re orientar el forma de tu pregunta, pues pedir opiniones sería motivo de cierre

Comment: Las apis ya estan creadas ? y expuestas  ? , de ser así puedes consumirlas con cualquier framework de frontend , el framework que utilices depende de la necesidad de tu compañía o tu criterio , si necesitas crear las apis , por mi parte las creo y las expongo en C#  web api y las consumo con angular, pero puedes consumirlas y crearlas como quieras solo debes deifnir o que te definan en que quieren o van a trabajar

Comment: @nagatox creo que debes contextualizar mas la pregunta; debes de tener en cuenta que todo depende de como tengas estructurado tu proyecto: los una `API` la puedes consumir nativamente con el browser utilizando `fetch` si necesidad de ninguna libreria o framework externo, si deseas usar una libreria externa podrias usar `jQuery`, `Axios`, todo depende de tus necesidades.

Comment: Agradezco las opiniones.. tienen razon deberia haber mencionado que quiero usar API de gmail y llevarlas a mi aplicacion nodejs.. es por ello que si debo enfocarme o consumirlas en el frontend o backend .. cual es lo optimo .. o no hay misterio en ello y solo se consumen con algun framework

Comment: Si es una API pública, donde no necesitas una key para identificarte, no debería haber problemas que la accedas desde el frontend. Ahora, si es una API privada, donde no deberías compartir tu key privado con cualquier usuario que acceda a tu página, debes hacerlo desde el backend.

Comment: Comparto lo que comentan y añado que, si los datos que consumes de Gmail tienes que procesarlos, guardarlos o cualquier otra tarea que pueda suponer una carga excesiva para el front, entonces deberías hacer esos procesos desde back y consumir desde tu propio back la información procesada.

Answer (score 0):

si quieres consumir una api para obtener algún tipo de recurso externo y que se te muestren en el front es bastante sencillo, te dare un breve ejemplo con React.
**El ejemplo esta hecho por medio de un componente de clase, que me permite tener manejo de estados.(el ejemplo puede tener un error en sintaxis)**:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

export class Example2 extends React.Component {

// inicializo un objeto state con 2 atributos
state = {
    posts: [],
    isLoaded: false
}

// llamo al metodo componentDidMount() y este a su vez llama a la funcion/metodo getData
// esta se encarga del fetch
componentDidMount(){
    this.getData();
}

getData = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(resp => {
        console.log('status ', resp.status);
        return resp.json();
    })
    .then(datos => {
        // una vez recibida la data del endpoint
        console.log(datos);
        this.setState({
            posts: datos,
            // como recibi la data
            isLoaded: true
        })
    })
}

render(){
    return(
        <Fragment>
          <h2>Datos disponibles</h2>
          <ul>
              {this.state.isLoaded ? (
                  this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
                      return(<li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)
                  })
              ):(
                 <h4>lo siento no hay posts disponibles</h4>
              )
            }
          </ul>
        </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```